# אלי and עלי what's the difference?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, language

Could someone explain the difference between  (2 Samuel 15:4 for example) עלי and אלי (Ezra 9:4 for example)? what's the difference

They both refer to 'my' or 'me' because of the yod suffix right? 
One seems to denote a preposition meaning on, upon, above, over, about, on top, atop, of, onto, at. While the other denotes a preposition meaning to, toward, at, into, in direction of, onto, unto. But that doesn't clearify the (true) difference for me. So what exactly is the difference is usage, definition and meaning or are they interchangeable and synonymous?

Comment: One correction: it's Ezra 9:5. But that aside, using Ezra as an example in questions about the Hebrew language might not be the best idea, because Ezra is part Aramaic and depicts Hebrew of a different era.

Comment: @ezra "different" from what?

Comment: @msh210 - The OP quotes Shmuel II in his example for the usage of עלי, and Ezra for the usage of אלי. There are some language differences between the Hebrew spoken at the time of David versus Galus Bavel and beyond. Sorry that was not clear.

Comment: To the VTCers: How many times do we have to go through this? Questions about Hebrew as used in Tanach is on-topic.

Comment: @ezra Mechon Mamre translation gives Ezra 9:4 וְאֵלַי יֵאָסְפוּ etc. but this word could be also found in Job 4:12 and Hosea 7:15 and without the prefix vav it's found in many other verses within the Tenach. But thank you for pointing out that part of Ezra is Aramaic.

Comment: P.s. Shir HaShirim 7:11 has a form of על while a comparable verse like Bereshit 3:16 (and 4:7) has a form of אל , same question aplies to these verses.